# Prove $|V(G)| \ge k^2 + 1$ when all vertices in a graph $G$ have degree at least $k$

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose the shortest cycle in graph $G$ has length $5$. Prove that if every vertex of $G$ has degree at least $k$, then $G$ has at least $k^2+1$ vertices.

So far, I have

$k \neq 0$, $k \neq 1$, or else we wouldn't have a cycle at all

If $k = 2$, then we would have a cycle (and by our question, it would be a $5$-cycle), and it would fit that $G$ has at least $k^2+1$ vertices ($2^2 + 1 = 5$).

My struggle is when $k \geq 3$. I know if I take any two vertices $u, v$, then each has $k-1$ neighbours other than each other, and that no neighbours of $u$ can be a neighbour of $v$ (else we'd have a smaller cycle of $3$). I'm not sure how to restrict it to be a size of $5$ though. Any advice?

Answer (score 3):

Suppose we have a graph $G$ with shortest cycle with length at least $5$ and every vertex with degree at least $k$.

Pick a vertex $v_1$ in the graph. $v_1$ has degree at least $k$, so it is connected to $k$ other (distinct) vertices $v_2, v_3, \dots, v_{k+1}$. Now, each of these vertices is connected to at least $k$ other vertices and these vertices must all be distinct as well (as otherwise there would be a triangle in the graph). Therefore we have found at least $k^2 + 1$ distinct vertices in the graph.

Comment: Suppose $x_1,\ldots,x_{k-1}$ are the $k-1$ other (distinct) vertices that are adjacent to $v_2$ and that $y_1,\ldots,y_{k-1}$ are the $k-1$ other (distinct) vertices that are adjacent to $v_3$. I agree that all of the $x_i$ and $y_i$ vertices are different from the $v_i$ vertices. But how do we know that the $x_i$ and $y_i$ vertices are different from each other?

Comment: If $x_1 = y_1$ then $v_1 - v_2 - x_1 - v_3 - v_1$ is a length $4$ cycle.

Comment: Why is $v_2$ connected to $k$ other vertices? Its degree is $k$ and it’s already connected to $v_1$ so shouldn’t it be connected to $k-1$ vertices? Im so confused.